# Mysql Producing changes/tuning ONLY in a Master

Tags: mysql

Is possible to tune a mysql slave server without applying the same changes on the master?
We say for example a innodb buffer running?
What about enabling multi-threading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is YES.
that is a normal practise when upgrading MYSQL Databases. You upgrade the slave and then you promote it as a Master, then you work on the old master..(for example)